# Connecting two Queue Channels backed by JDBC Store in Spring Intgegration DSL

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm trying to connect two Queue Channels (backed by JDBC Store).

```
@Configuration
public class DemoIntegration {
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow(MessageChannel firstJDBCChannel,
                                MessageChannel secondJDBCChannel) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(firstJDBCChannel)
                .bridge(bridgeHandler -> bridgeHandler.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(100L)))
                .handle(secondJDBCChannel)
                .get();
    }
}
```

I tried to put different constructions between this two channels and still have an error like:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous
>   parameter type [class java.lang.Void] for method match: [public
>   boolean
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractPollableChannel.removeInterceptor(org.springframework.messaging.support.ChannelInterceptor),
>   public org.springframework.messaging.Message
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractPollableChannel.receive(long),
>   public final void
>   org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setPrimaryExpression(org.springframework.expression.Expression),
>   public void
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.setStatsEnabled(boolean),
>   public void
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.setMessageConverter(org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter),
>   public void
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.setDatatypes(java.lang.Class...),
>   public void
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.configureMetrics(org.springframework.integration.support.management.AbstractMessageChannelMetrics),
>   public void
>   org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setComponentName(java.lang.String),
>   public org.springframework.messaging.support.ChannelInterceptor
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractPollableChannel.removeInterceptor(int),
>   public void
>   org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setMessageBuilderFactory(org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilderFactory),
>   public java.util.List>
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel.purge(org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSelector),
>   public void
>   org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext)
>   throws org.springframework.beans.BeansException, public void
>   org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setBeanFactory(org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory),
>   public org.springframework.expression.Expression
>   org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.getExpression(),
>   public void
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractPollableChannel.setInterceptors(java.util.List),
>   public void
>   org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.setChannelResolver(org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolver)]
>     at org.springframework.util.Assert.isNull(Assert.java:155)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.findHandlerMethodsForTarget(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:776)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:379)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:225)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:220)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:60)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:38)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:924)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:904)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]    at
>   org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.handle(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:891)
>   ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]    at
>   name.karwowski.blazej.integrationdemo2.DemoIntegration.flow(DemoIntegration.java:16)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   name.karwowski.blazej.integrationdemo2.DemoIntegration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f82aadc3.CGLIB$flow$0()
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   name.karwowski.blazej.integrationdemo2.DemoIntegration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f82aadc3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ef9b4b0c.invoke()
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]     at
>   name.karwowski.blazej.integrationdemo2.DemoIntegration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f82aadc3.flow()
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:155)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]   ... 19 common frames
>   omitted

How to correctly connect two (or more) queue channels? I need to make some processing between them and allow application to retain messages in case of stop.

Full log and code sample are on github: https://github.com/blazejkarwowski/integration-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.handle(secondJDBCChannel)` you have to use `.channel(secondJDBCChannel)`. There is nothing to handle - it is a Channel in between.

See [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/java-dsl.html)  for more info.